# WordPress in subdirectory has wrong upload_dir

Tags: wordpress, upload, subdirectory

I have a WP installation in the root-folder, and some other WP installations in sub-directories

- example.com => has WP-installation in root folder
- example.com/project1 => folder named "project1" resides in root and has own WP-installation

everything works fine, except uploads.

Let's say, I'm in example.com/project1/wp-admin and want to upload a file:

**Expected behaviour:**

- file is uploaded to /project1/wp-content/uploads
- DB-entry is created in project1-database

**Actual behaviour:**

- file is uploaded to /wp-content/uploads (root-folder)
- DB-entry is created in project1-database

I've tried changing upload_dir, resulting into the same behaviour:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'project1/wp-content/uploads');
```

I also tried changing the wp_content_dir:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).'/project1/wp-content' );
```

But this gives me an error, like "Can't upload to /project1/wp-content/uploads/2018/09'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using a Multisite installation?

Comment: Also, the constant is `UPLOADS`, not `UPLOAD`.

Comment: sorry... that was a typo... I had `UPLOADS`. yes there is a reason, I've picked up a project, that another developer started, and I'm stuck with his initial setup :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it fixed now:

I was on the right path with:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).'/project1/wp-content' );
```

The error that I got, was because I created the folder for the mounth by hand as root, and therefore the **permissions** were wrong.